# Call script from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is there any other BEST way then what i'm doing.?

What is best practice .?

Why jQuery.post is not working.?

Button

```
<input class="button subbutton" type="submit" value="Subscribe Me" name="Submit">
```

Inputbox

```
<input id="user_email" class="inputbox" type="text" name="user[email]" >
```

JavaScript Not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("input[name='Submit']").click(function(){
    PostUniqueID = '123456789';
    var PostEmail = document.getElementById('user_email').value;
    jQuery.post("http://www.myfile.com/programs/SignUpAutomate.php", { 
      getUniqueID : PostUniqueID ,
      GetEmailJVFunction : PostEmail});   
  });
</script>
```

JavaScript Working

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery("input[name='Submit']").click(function(){
 alert('working good..!!');
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Chances are it's not working because of cross-domain restrictions. Check your JavaScript console.

Comment: Same kind of logic working for another script only diffrence there I have button ID here i don't have. both file are in same server.

Comment: whats not working about it? where is your `jQuery.post` callback?

Comment: There is no call back PHP script is simply upload record in table. PHP script working perfect If I run from Browser manually.

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: I'm wondering if brackets are allowed in `name="user[email]"`...?

Comment: I'm kind of thinking how can you run a HTTP POST request from your browser...? You may have a PHP issue - the best way to do test it would be to add the callback function to the jQuery post request, so it would look something like  
`jQuery.post("http://www.myfile.com/programs/SignUpAutomate.php", {  
      getUniqueID : PostUniqueID,  
      GetEmailJVFunction : PostEmail  
 }, function(response) { console.debug(response); } );`  

This way you would see the PHP response and can debug that part. (You should be looking at `$_POST['user']['email']` or $_REQUEST['user']['email']` in your PHP.)

Comment: It should say 'working well' try that